# TextView alignment according to text length

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need something like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/utQUq.png

When text in TextView is not so long, it must be centered in parent layout. But when text becomes longer to be centered correctly, we need to align it to the left.

Comment: But why do you want to do that? anyways if the text length is long it grows symmetrically. so at a point when it  occupies the whole TextView it will look like gravity=left or right.

Comment: What kind of layout are you talking about? I am using RelativeLayout with ImageView and TextView inside and it is not working.

Comment: in this case (RelativeLayout, ImageView & TextView inside) TextView dont know anything about ImageView's existance (i don't know how to say it better) and centered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can write if condition according to the size of the text and you can set the alignment. Here is a sample code:

```
if(mytextview.getText.length() >10)
{
mytextview.setGravity("LEFT");
}
```

Keep your default gravity to center.

Comment: Gravity to center is not working in my RelativeLayout. To align to center I am using android:layout_centerInParent

Comment: and of course, this recommendation is unsuitable because the max length of text may vary on different screen sizes